# Pod Stuck in Terminating State Due to iptables 'Chain Already Exists' Error in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, iptables

I'm facing an unusual issue with a Kubernetes deployment using the Mailu Helm chart, specifically the `mailu-front` component. After updating the deployment, the newly created pod works fine, but the old pod gets stuck in the 'terminating' state. The Kubernetes event log shows the following error related to pod termination:

```
error killing pod: failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "237aa644-7634-4fa2-a538-f973e7f7dfab" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to destroy network for sandbox \"cbbcf6eaaf47c0ef5b92b97187276d04def7bcef3e68b92889b7993ba970ce55\": plugin type=\"portmap\" failed (delete): could not teardown ipv4 dnat: running [/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -N CNI-DN-0e851981d24bd2d807e1a --wait]: exit status 1: iptables: Chain already exists.\n"
```

I'm running a small kubeadm 1.28 cluster with Weave CNI and Debian 11 host OS for all nodes

Attempts to force delete the pod have been unsuccessful. This issue seems to be related to an iptables configuration, specifically a conflict where a chain cannot be torn down because it already exists (conflicting, since the command in the event log intends to create the chain, not delete it).

I've not found much information on how to resolve this particular error.

If I log into the host OS of the affected node and run `sudo iptables -t nat -N CNI-DN-0e851981d24bd2d807e1a --wait` , I can indeed see the issue reflected in the output:

```
iptables: Chain already exists.
```

If I try to delete the chain with `sudo iptables -t nat -X CNI-DN-0e851981d24bd2d807e1a --wait`, iptables says the chain is already in use:

```
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables):  CHAIN_USER_DEL failed (Device or resource busy): chain CNI-DN-0e851981d24bd2d807e1a
```

I tried restarting the node but the problem still occurs.

Comment: I have updated the answer based on your response.Let me know if the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just restarting the entire cluster and the problem went away. I think it's something to do with when I do a rolling update and multiple pods are starting/deleting at once. Next time the problem occurs, I'll try your updated solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the previous **termination cleanup** is not completed. If you attempt to **Force delete** that might cause some unexpected results like resource leak due to an incomplete cleanup process.

Try below diagnosis steps for further cleanup processes of the related resources on the kubernetes node while the Pod is still stuck in the `Terminating` state.

- SSH into the target kubernetes node
- Execute `crictl ps` to confirm the CONTAINER_ID
- Execute `crictl pods` to confirm the POD_ID
- Execute `crictl stop CONTAINER_ID` to stop the container
- Related resources should be automatically deleted by `kubelet`, without user intervention.
- Wait for a few minutes, double check if the container and pod is still existing. If yes, execute `crictl rm <CONTAINER_ID>` and       `crictl rmp <POD_ID>` to remove accordingly.

You can refer to the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/crictl/) for more information.

**UPDATE:**

As per this [link](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=70130),
You can try `iptables -F <CHAINNAMEHERE>`
followed by `iptables -X <CHAINNAMEHERE>`

It appears -F deletes all the rules in a chain but not the chain itself. So it is necessary to follow up with a -X.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find any containers on any of my nodes that are the ones stuck in "terminating".